# golang errgroup example without channels

Tags: go, concurrency

I saw the [example](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup#example-Group--Parallel) of errgroup in godoc, and it makes me confused that it simply assigns the result to global results instead of using channels in each search routines. Heres the code:

```
Google := func(ctx context.Context, query string) ([]Result, error) {
g, ctx := errgroup.WithContext(ctx)

searches := []Search{Web, Image, Video}
results := make([]Result, len(searches))
for i, search := range searches {
    i, search := i, search // https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines
    g.Go(func() error {
        result, err := search(ctx, query)
        if err == nil {
            results[i] = result
        }
        return err
    })
}
if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
return results, nil
```

}

I'm not sure is there any reason or implied rules guarantees it is correct? THX

Comment: There are o globals in the example code. Can you explain what exactly you do not understand about this code, especially the errgoup stuff (the rest is just for demonstration).

Comment: you mean the **results** is not a global variable? but it is manupulated in 3 routines created by  **g.Go**. I just wondering is there any thread safety problem here.

Comment: Yes. The variable `results` is not global, it is local to the function `Google`. And it is  **not** manipulated by the goroutines. Really, it isn't. Because that _would_ be a "thread safety problem", i.e. it would be racy and thus wrong. The different goroutines each write to **their** **own** slice element `results[i]`. Each slice element is "thing" of it own and accessing different things concurrently is not racy (roughly).

Comment: Maybe each element in slice is not racy, but how to guarantees elements is visible in outer routine (or write in sub routines does not have a *happens before* relation with read in outer routine)? THX

Comment: @user5487705, the main goroutine doesn't do anything with `results` before `g.Wait()` returns, and `g.Wait` doesn't return before all goroutines have finished executing (that's the whole point of the errgroup).

Comment: Although `g.Wait()` returns until all goroutines finished, is there still any possiblity that the main routine does not get the correct result because of the existence of CPU cache or sth?  Thank you for your patience

Comment: No, absolutely not. The _whole_ raison d'être of errgroup is to _prevent_ such problems totally.

Answer (score 0):

The intent here is to make `searches` and `results` congruent. The result for the `Web` search is always at `results[0]`, the result for the `Image` search always at `results[1]`, etc. It also makes for a simpler example, because there is no need for an additional goroutine that consumes a channel.

If the goroutines would send their results into a channel, the result order would be unpredictable. If predictable result order is not a property you care about feel free to use a channel.

Answer (score 0):

There is secret sauce in this code that creates siloing:

```
results := make([]Result, len(searches))
           ^^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

for i, search := ... {
    i, search := i, search
          ^^^^^^^^^^
    g.Go {
        results[i] = result
        ^^^^^^^^^^
    }
```

We know how big the result set is going to be, so we pre-allocate all the slots before starting any goroutines. This eliminates any contention over the slice object itself

```
make(.., len(searches))
^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

We then promote the index number and search property to a closure for each iteration, so there is no contention over the variables being used by the loop/goroutines

```
    i, search := i, search
```

And finally, each worker operates on a singular slot in the pre-sized slice:

```
        results[i] = result
```

The workers are guaranteed to only perform read operations on the "results" slice to find out where their element is (`results[i]`).

This particular pattern is limiting, you can't use the results until all the workers are completed. So ask yourself what you're going to do next when deciding whether to use this or a channels-based pipeline workflow.

```
results := getSearchResults(searches)
statistics := analyzeResults(results)
for stats := range statistics {
    our.Write("{%s}\n", stats.String())
}
```

If the analysis of a given result is independent of any other, this is a good candidate for a channel-based workflow.

But if the analysis depends on order, or has different results depending on each other then you may not have any choice but to serialize the flow.